# Custom API Controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to create a custom API Controller method.
I want to call it by using /api/optionalgroup/getbypricelist/{id}
But cant get it to work.

This is my WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ApiByAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
        Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
}
```

}

And this is my ApiController

```
    public class OptionalGroupController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/optionalgroup
        public IEnumerable<string> GetByPricelist(int id)
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/optionalgroup/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/optionalgroup
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/optionalgroup/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/optionalgroup/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But when i try to call it using uri /api/optionalgroup/getbypricelist/5 it doesnt work, but if i replace the GetByPricelist method with the default Get() it works with uri /api/optionalgroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. 
Just replaced the ApiConfig line 
`routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"`, 
with 
`routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`